# Display a receiver device's status when not connected

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

In order to follow the [design checklist](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#sender-cast-menu-available), I'm trying to display the status of a cast device in the cast menu when not connected.

> Each receiver in the list shows a state below its name. The receiver state is the device model when idle (e.g. Chromecast) and a status when connected (e.g. "Casting YouTube").

Getting the model device is easy with the `modelName` property of `GCKDevice` but I wonder if there is an easy way to get the status without having to connect to the device first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that you need to do on the sender side; the SDK should populate that with the appropriate information; the first line of each route would be its name and the second line would contain information that the "receiver" of the running app provides (Application Status). If you want your recevier to provide that information, make sure that your receiver contains `CastReceiverManager.setApplicationStatus("YOUR_RECEIVER_STATUS")` where `"YOUR_RECEIVER_STATUS"` could be something like "Playing Buck Bunny". If a receiver doesn't provide any info, the SDK will just populate the second line by the type of receiver, for example "Chormecast"; due to privacy concerns, SDK doesn't try to figure out what is playing there on its own (even if it was possible to do).

You may also want to take a look at this G+ [post](https://plus.google.com/113603561173832215383/posts/NYcEkwWDiWu).

Comment: Unfortunately setting the [applicationState](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.html#setApplicationState) on the custom receiver does not affect the content of the detail line  in the cast menu.`cell.detailTextLabel.text = device.modelName;` (from the ux compliant demo app `CastVideos-ios`)